# SQL LEFT JOIN on Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join

Given three tables:

1. `Account`

   1. `UniqueID`
   2. `Account Group`
2. `VR`

   1. `UniqueID`
   2. `AccountID`
3. `CR`

   1. `UniqueID`
   2. `AccountID`

where `AccountID` found in `VR` and `CR` reference the `UniqueID` in `Account`.

I would like to obtain a result which shows me the `Account` groups of `Account` in the first column and the amount of data per `Account` group of `VR` in the second column and finally the amount of data of per `Account` group in column three form `CR`.

What's the right way do implement that kind of join?

My attempt:

```
SELECT account_group AS 'Account Group',
  COUNT(Account.AccountId) AS 'Anzahl Accounts',
  COUNT(VR.ActivityId) AS 'VR',
  COUNT(Contact.ContactId) AS 'Contact'
  FROM [MSCRM].[dbo].[AccountBase]
  LEFT JOIN MSCRM.dbo.visit_report_activityBase
    ON Account.AccountId = VR.account_id
  LEFT JOIN MSCRM.dbo.ContactBase
    ON Account.AccountId = Contact.ParentCustomerId
  GROUP BY account_group
  ORDER BY account_group ASC;
```

But no `COUNT(*)` shows the actual amount I desire.

Even the `COUNT` of `Account.AccountId` shows an invalid number.

Comment: Show us some of the actual data, and the result you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is count distinct :

```
SELECT account_group as 'Account Group',
       count(distinct Account.AccountId) as 'Anzahl Accounts',
       count(distinct VR.ActivityId) as 'VR' count(distinct Contact.ContactId) as 'Contact'
  FROM [ MSCRM ] . [ dbo ] . [ AccountBase ] as Account
  left join MSCRM.dbo.visit_report_activityBase as VR
    on Account.AccountId = VR.account_id
  left join MSCRM.dbo.ContactBase as Contact
    on Account.AccountId = Contact.ParentCustomerId
 group by account_group
 order by account_group
```